# dev-c++ g++ - error: typename/static constant undeclared (first use this function)

Tags: c++, templates, g++, dev-c++, typename

I keep getting the following errors about typename posizione and int constant POSIZIONENULLA. Strangely I have used type posizione throught my code, but get the errors only in the the function.

```
Coda.h:156: error: `template<class T> class Coda' used without template parameters
Coda.h: In function `typename Coda<T>::posizione copiaNodo(typename Coda<T>::posizione)':
Coda.h:158: error: `POSIZIONENULLA' undeclared (first use this function)
Coda.h:158: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
Coda.h:161: error: `posizione' undeclared (first use this function)
Coda.h:161: error: expected `;' before "tempPosizione"
Coda.h:162: error: `tempPosizione' undeclared (first use this function)
Coda.h:164: error: `temPosizione' undeclared (first use this function)
Coda.h: At global scope:
Coda.h:169: error: `template<class T> class Coda' used without template parameters
Coda.h: In function `void eliminaNodo(typename Coda<T>::posizione)':
Coda.h:171: error: `POSIZIONENULLA' undeclared (first use this function)
Coda.h:173: error: `posizione' undeclared (first use this function)
Coda.h:173: error: expected `;' before "tempPosizione"
Coda.h:175: error: `tempPosizione' undeclared (first use this function) make: *** [Coda.o] Error 1
```

I am using dev-c++ 4.9.9.2 with g++

I have uploaded the whole source code @ http://ge.tt/9I0pXcS/v/0?c for you to compile. for compilation you can use the make file in folder "Coda" or launch the following commands in the compiler folder.

g++ -g -c Coda.h -o Coda.o
ar crf Coda.a Coda.o

I really help you can me. Thanks you very much in advance for your time. Thanks.

Comment: And no code as far as I'm aware. Please reduce it to a reasonable size (see http://sscce.org) and post it here, taking care to use the format code (`{}`) button.

Comment: @Chris 

I have uploaded the whole source code @ http://ge.tt/9I0pXcS/v/0?c for you to compile. for compilation you can use the make file in folder "Coda" or launch the following commands in the compiler folder.

Comment: Ok, I haven't actually unpacked the zip and looked at the code, but according the error message, you used `Coda` without specifying the template argument. You need something like `Coda<T>` with a suitable choice of `T`.

Comment: @jogojapan I applied the principle you say throught my code. however in two funcions I am getting the error. I think is relate so template issue anyway,dven thoug I can't tell what that is...

Comment: Please update your IDE to the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 or 4.7.0, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`` Coda.h:156: error: `template<class T> class Coda' used without template parameters ``

This tells you that you have put `Coda` instead of `Coda<something>`.

`` Coda.h:158: error: `POSIZIONENULLA' undeclared (first use this function) ``

You haven't declare `POSIZIONENULLA`.

`` Coda.h:161: error: `posizione' undeclared (first use this function) ``

Same.

`` Coda.h:161: error: expected `;' before "tempPosizione" ``

You forgot a semicolon `;` in line 161

`` Coda.h:162: error: `tempPosizione' undeclared (first use this function) `` and `` Coda.h:164: error: `temPosizione' undeclared (first use this function) ``

Same as above.

Comment: Thanks very much! all the errors are now fixed. thank you very much I really appreciate your contribution!

Comment: You are welcome, my advice is that you get familiarized with the errors you get so you can solve them easily as you see them.